# Создание калькулятора с помощью функций

Tags: javascript, функции, калькулятор

В задании требуется создать функции, которые будут выполнять следующие условия:

1. Для каждого числа должна быть своя функция, т.е. от 0 (“zero”) до 9 (“nine”);
2. Должна быть функция для каждой из следующих математических операций: plus, minus, times (умножение), dividedBy (деление);
3. Самая внешняя функция представляет собой левый операнд, самая внутренняя функция представляет собой правый операнд;

```
//Вызов должен иметь такой вид:
seven(times(five()));
//Результат:
Результат: 7 * 5 = 35
```

Comment: Где Ваша попытка решить задачу?

Comment: Я долго пыталась, но у меня не получалось. В конечном итоге я полностью удалила его

Comment: Тут не решают задачи за Вас, тут помогают их решить, если у Вас возникли какие-либо проблемы, пожалуйста, выложите Ваши попытки решить задачу и посмотрим.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду в этом плане внимательнее

Answer (score 3):

```js
function five(op) {
  if (!op) return function() {return 5};
  return op(5);
}

function seven(op) {
  if (!op) return function() {return 7};
  return op(7);
}

function times(num) {
  return function (a) {return a * num()};
}

console.log(seven(times(five())))
```

Остальное по аналогии.

Answer (score 0):

```
const numberDictionary = {
  zero: 0,
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4,
  five: 5,
  six: 6,
  seven: 7,
  eight: 8,
  nine: 9
}

for(const key in numberDictionary) {
 eval(`function ${key}(operation) { return operation ? operation(${numberDictionary[key]}) : ${numberDictionary[key]}; }`)
}

const operationsDictionary = {
  plus: "+",
  minus: "-",
  times: "*",
  dividedBy: "/"
}

for(const key in operationsDictionary) {
  eval(`function ${key}(rightOperand) { return (leftOperand) => leftOperand ${operationsDictionary[key]} rightOperand;  }`);
}
```

Вот так можно сгенерировать функции на все случаи, что бы не писать каждую функцию с нуля, особенно с учётом того что отличаются они только цифрой или оператором.

Comment: правда не люблю eval, но аналога в данной ситуации не могу придумать.